# Use function to change data frame in place

Tags: python, pandas, function, scipy

I have a simple function which produces the desired output. I would like to find a way to make this change "in place" within the function. I would like the `NCE_to_PR(df.pr)` to change `df`.

**Code:**

```
import scipy.stats
from scipy.stats import norm
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':list(range(0,7)), 'pr':[26,54,73,30,58,42,88]}) 

def NCE_to_PR(pd_series):
    pd_series=  (norm.cdf((pd.to_numeric(pd_series)-50)/21.06))*100
    print(pd_series)

NCE_to_PR(df.pr)
```

---

*Note:* My purpose requires a general solution, so any reference of the original data frame, within the function will not be feasible.

Comment: Is there no way in your code to refactor this to return your desired output instead?

Comment: Why not change `print(pd_series)` to `return(pd_series)` and use `df.pr  = NCE_to_PR(df.pr)`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @not_speshal, but that's is not what I'm looking for. This is a very small part of a series of codes that will be imported into other scripts to be used as parts of other functions. That is why it is import for the change to happen within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against this practice, but build in method `update` ([documentation link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html)) is probably what you are looking for:

```
def NCE_to_PR(pd_series):
    new_values = (norm.cdf((pd.to_numeric(pd_series)-50)/21.06))*100
    pd_series.update(pd.Series(new_values))
```

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, what is the reason that you would advise against this method? What issues am I likely to encounter?

Comment: I don't have great experiences with custom functions changing some dataframe in place, it is so hard to read, what is happening. I also think that `update` is slower than simple `df['col_name] = new_series` and be carefull that method `update` also ignores all 'NaN' in new series.